# Troubleshooting a jQuery code to change CSS onclick

Tags: jquery

This was my first go at writing some jQuery code completely from scratch, so aside from the fact that I went wrong somewhere, I'm also not sure if this is the best way to do what I'm trying to do. Here goes!

I'm using [jQuery Swipe.js](http://swipejs.com/) to control a slider on a mobile site. The slider contains 3 divs. I also have some left/right arrow buttons that a user can click that calls the Swipe function.

I want to hide/show some divs when the swipe action is called, depending on what is currently in the viewport. I've tried to do this using a simple variable, `i`, which is added/subtracted from depending on the current page the user is viewing.

The original script to call the swipe.js function was simply `var slider = new Swipe(document.getElementById('slider'));`

The script code that I wrote is this: **//EDIT: Updated after reviewing the Swipe documentation**

```
var slider = new Swipe(document.getElementById('slider'), {
      callback: function() {

        var pageNumber = slider.getPos();
        if (pageNumber = 0) {
            $(".leftArrow").css("display", "none");
            $("footer#about").css("display", "none");       
            $("footer#adFooter").css("display", "none");
        }

        else if (pageNumber = 1) {
            $(".leftArrow").css("display", "inline");
            $("footer#adFooter").css("display", "inline");          
            $("footer#about").css("display", "none");

        }

        else if (pageNumber = 2) {
            $("footer#adFooter").css("display", "none");        
            $("footer#about").css("display", "inline");
        }     
    }
});
```

The HTML code is this:

```
<a href='#' onclick='slider.prev(); return false;'><img class="leftArrow" src="img/arrow_right.png" alt="Left Nav Arrow"/></a>
<a href='#' style="" onclick='slider.next(); return false;'><img class="rightArrow" src="img/arrow_right.png" alt="Right Nav Arrow"/></a>
```

I can't exactly see where I've gone wrong here, but evidently the whole thing isn't working. Thoughts?

Comment: I'm wondering why you used the variable name `i` as a placeholder for `pageNumber`.  Can you enlighten me?

Comment: I've been going through the codecademy javascript into courses and that's just the variable that was used there. Will try a different variable and use your suggestion below and report back.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to add a comment at codeacademy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what problems you are having, but one problem is clear.  `i` can be both `-1` and `3`.  Change your two if statements to say `i>0` and `i<2` and don't include the `=` as you do now.

Comment: Used your suggestions, but still not working. In Chrome's console I'm not seeing any errors, but clicking the arrows does absolutely nothing. (whereas when the code was originally `var slider = new Swipe(document.getElementById('slider'));` the slide function worked fine. Also, ALL of the divs are being displayed when loading the page, Here's a live version of the broken site: http://harrisonfjord.com/folio/ and here's it working before I changed the code: http://harrisonfjord.com/folio/indexBackup.html

Comment: I see the problem but I don't have time to fix it now -- I suggest looking at the documentation for Swipe and searching for more examples using that plugin.  Right now your code does not actually make a swipe element.

Comment: See updated code above, after viewing swipe documentation (didn't realise there was more on Github) I see you can add a callback function, plus there's a getPos() function there already. I think I'm close (at least, I hope...), the slide function is working properly now although nothing I've put in the callback function seems to be working at all... Updated live at http://harrisonfjord.com/folio/

Comment: Another problem I see is that you use = for comparison when you should be using === or at least ==.

Comment: I am an idiot, despite only knowing a little javascript that was one of teh first things I learned. That fixed it! Thanks lowerkey!

Comment: @Jascination I'm glad you solved it -- had a long day at work and did not get a chance to help.